# Writing a matrix out to text file by rows rather than columns

Tags: matlab

I have a script to extract a bunch of x,y,z coords from a Matlab program. They populate a 3 column matrix. I then need to write this matrix out to a text file so I have a coordinate file for a separate program. The code to write stuff out is as follows:

```
Coords = crop_points %just a 3 column array with a bunch of x,y,z coords
CoordOutput = fopen('coords.txt', 'a+') %Opening a text file that I will append as I want more than one set of coords added to this
fprintf(CoordOutput, '%d %d %d\n', Coords) %This is where it all goes wrong
```

Coords would be a matrix that looks something like:

```
1045 1300 200
1500 1400 250
378 450 120
```

But be 1000+ rows long with each number being in a separate cell.

The output text file will for some reason then look like:

```
1045 1500 378
1300 1400 450
200 250 120
```

Currently rather than adding each row of the matrix to each row of the text file it adds each row to the current column of the text file but makes the text file 3 equally sized columns.

I assume I am miss-using `fprintf` but looking at the documentation I am not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab use [column- major representation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/what-are-column-major-and-row-major-representation-1.html) of the matrix, so it reads it column-wise and just prints the values in triplets as you denoted by `'%d %d %d'`. To print the matrix correctly simply transpose it:

```
fprintf(CoordOutput, '%d %d %d \n', Coords.') % note the .' after the matrix name
```

Also, notice that your (original) slash is backward, though if you don't see it in the printed file it's probably a mistake in the question.

OR, you can use [`dlmwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html?s_tid=doc_ta) with a space delimiter:

```
dlmwrite('coords.txt',Coords,'delimiter',' ')
```

(no need for `fopen` before that, only the line above)

Comment: Thank you, dlmwrite works perfectly when I just add the -append flag.